# Перенаправление форм django

Tags: python, form, django

Есть html форма, которая состоит из нескольких полей. В одном из полей типа select пользователь может выбирать несколько вариантов, и кроме того, возле этого поля есть кнопка "добавить свой вариант". При нажатии на эту кнопку пользователь перенапрявляется на страницу с новой формой, где вводит свой вариант, отправляет его и возвращается на страницу с первой формой.

Как сделать так с помощью только инструментов python, чтобы введенные ранее даные в первой форме сохранились после возвращения со второй формы.

Comment: @hyral, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите чисто питоном - делаете кнопку типа submit, и данные кладете в сессию, либо в базу с флагом active=False. Но я бы сделал на клиенте, положил бы данные в cookies или localStorage. Почти уверен, что есть готовая библиотека для jQuery, например.

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов - записать в сессию